# Count numbers of repetitive words in a string without breaking order

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a string like this `var str = "S3;S4;S3;S4;S5;S5;S4;S4;S4"`, I would like to split this into a list like this,

`{ {"S3" : 1}, {"S4" : 1}, {"S3" : 1}, {"S4" : 1}, {"S5" : 2}, {"S4" : 3} }`

Basically a count for each word in the sequence. I tried to use LINQ group by but it will only give me a sorted list of unique word. Is there a way that I can maintain the order and just count the repetitions of a word?

Thanks for any suggestions or help!

This is what I have so far

```
var text = "S3;S4;S5;S5;S4;S4;S3;S3;S3;S4;";
var list = text.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var grouped = from state in list group state by state.ToState() into g select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

I'm trying to use LINQ by the way...

Please take a look at serhiyb's answer for a non LINQ/Regex and Xiaoy312 for a LINQ/Regex and really nice solution!

Comment: use GroupBy extension method. Like this => str.Split(";").GroupBy(p => p).ToDictionary(p => p, p => p.Count())

Comment: And you shouldn't be using LINQ by the way, because non LINQ solution is trivial.

Comment: but that would sort the list into something like this `{{S3, count}, {S4, count}}` and will not maintain the order of the string?

Comment: `state.ToState()` has no meaning unless you have a `.ToState()` extension method on the string class.

Comment: @IvanStoev how would you go about that? I'm not really good with algorithm :/

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn You're correct sir. I do have a ToState() extension.

Comment: Makes more sense. What does that return? We need to know how whatever that returns handles IEquatable.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That returns an enumeration for each type of matched string, i.e. S3 = Commercial, S4 = Private, etc.

Comment: It's an enum? Just need to be sure of that. Also, I want to check your expected results. Are you sure you don't want this result from that input:

 `{ {"S3":2} ,{"S4":5} ,{"S5":2} }` ?

Comment: And do you really need to convert to an enum, given the string values are what you want in the result?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Joel, I do not want a dictionary list. Thanks bud!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by mixing `Regex` and little bit of `LINQ` :

```
Regex.Matches("S3;S4;S5;S5;S4;S4;S3;S3;S3;S4;", @"(?<key>.+?)(?<repeated>;\k<key>)*;")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Key = x.Groups["key"].Value,
        Count = 1 + x.Groups["repeated"].Captures.Count
    })
```

---

The `Regex` matches the followings :

- `(?<key>.+?)` matches anything and put it into a named group `key`
- `(?<repeated>;\k<key>)` matches any number of repetitions of previously matched key

Result:

```
Key Count
S3 1 
S4 1 
S5 2 
S4 2 
S3 3 
S4 1
```

Comment: Be careful. He's not looking for `{ {"S3":2} ,{"S4":5} ,{"S5":2} }`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Where did you get that? It outputs : S3 1 
S4 1 
S5 2 
S4 2 
S3 3 
S4 1

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Yeah, I think you're totally right. Thank you

Comment: Technically, it doesn't output anything :D.  Though I see now that it does produce the correct data.

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = "S3;S4;S5;S5;S4;S4;S3;S3;S3;S4;";
var list = text.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

var current = list[0];
var len = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < list.Length; ++i)
{
    if (current == list[i]){
        ++len;
    }
    else{
        result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(current, len));
        current = list[i];
        len = 1;
    }
}
result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(current, len));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result.Select(p => "{" +p.Key + "," + p.Value + "}" )));
```

Live demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aOOrHb

and solution with linq "hacks":

```
    var text = "S3;S4;S5;S5;S4;S4;S3;S3;S3;S4;";
    var list = text.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Concat(new [] {string.Empty});

    var groupIndex = 1;

    var result = list
        .Skip(1)
        .Zip(list, (cur, prev) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(cur != prev && groupIndex > 1 ? string.Empty : string.IsNullOrEmpty(prev) ? cur : prev, cur == prev ? ++groupIndex : (groupIndex = 1) )).ToList()
        .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Key));

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result.Select(p => "{" +p.Key + "," + p.Value + "}" )));
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Is there a LINQ version of this? I'll mark your answer as best if no one could come up with a LINQ one.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is not well suited for tasks like this. The only LINQ method that allows you to maintain some state while processing the sequence elements is [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx), but it's just a LINQ-ish way to perform a `foreach` loop. Anyway, here it is:

```
var result = list.Aggregate(
    Enumerable.Repeat(new { Name = default(string), Count = default(int) }, 0).ToList(),
    (res, name) =>
    {
        int last = res.Count - 1;
        if (last >= 0 && res[last].Name == name)
            res[last] = new { Name = name, Count = res[last].Count + 1 };
        else
            res.Add(new { Name = name, Count = 1 });
        return res;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A real LINQ way to do this should not require to have the entire sequence in memory. This way requires a helper method and a few more lines, but I believe is easier to read and mantain IMHO.

```
var repetitions = "S3;S4;S5;S5;S4;S4;S3;S3;S3;S4"
    .Split(";".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .CountRepetitions();

    foreach (var kv in repetitions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kv.ToString());
    }
```

And the `CountRepetitions` method:

```
static class RepetitionHelper
{ 
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> CountRepetitions(this IEnumerable<string> list)
    {
        string last = null;
        int count = 1;

        foreach(string current in list)
        {
            if (last == null)
                last = current; // first element in the sequence
            else if (last == current)
                count++;        // repetition
            else
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, int>(last, count);
                count = 1;
                last = current;
            }
        }

        if (last != null) 
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, int>(last, count); 
    } 
}
```